# How to do a performance tuning on this query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing, query-optimization

I have the following query which is taking a long time (around 2hrs) to execute:

```
CREATE TABLE #compareList  
(
     id  INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
     poy_no varchar(max), 
     poy_stat_cd varchar(max), 
     poy_eff_dd datetime, 
     poy_exp_dd datetime,   
     [Name] [nvarchar] (max)
);
    
DECLARE @poy_no varchar(max), @poy_stat_cd varchar(max),
        @poy_eff_dd datetime, @poy_exp_dd datetime, @remarks nvarchar(max)

DECLARE C_Compare CURSOR STATIC FOR
    SELECT b.poy_no, b.poy_stat_cd, b.poy_eff_dd, b.poy_exp_dd, a.remarks    
    FROM table1 a  

OPEN C_Compare

FETCH NEXT FROM C_Compare 
    INTO @poy_no, @poy_stat_cd, @poy_eff_dd, @poy_exp_dd, @remarks

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #compareList 
        SELECT @poy_no, @poy_stat_cd, @poy_eff_dd, @poy_exp_dd, @remarks 

    FETCH NEXT FROM C_Compare 
        INTO @poy_no, @poy_stat_cd, @poy_eff_dd, @poy_exp_dd, @remarks
END

CLOSE C_Compare;
DEALLOCATE C_Compare;

-- This query has performance issue
SELECT
    COUNT(1)
FROM 
    #compareList a,
    (SELECT
          pid, single_string_name, original_script_name, 
          surname, first_name, middle_name 
      FROM 
          DJ_PERSON WITH (INDEX (NCIndex_all_needed_columns))) AS p,
    (SELECT pid, desc1 FROM PERSON_DESC) AS pd,
    DESC1 AS d
WHERE  
    p.pid = pd.pid
    AND pd.desc1 = d.d1id
    AND replace(replace(replace(rtrim(ltrim(a.name)), ' ',''), ',',''), '.','') != ''
    AND (replace(replace(replace(a.Name, ' ',''), ',',''), '.','') = replace(replace(replace(p.single_string_name, ' ',''), ',',''), '.','')
        COLLATE database_default
        OR replace(replace(replace(a.Name, ' ',''), ',',''), '.','') = replace(replace(replace(p.original_script_name, ' ',''), ',',''), '.','')
        COLLATE database_default
        OR
         replace(replace(replace(a.Name, ' ',''), ',',''), '.','') = replace(replace(replace(p.surname+p.first_name+p.middle_name, ' ',''), ',',''), '.','')
        )
```

Below is the count of rows for each table. The tables `PERSON` and `PERSON_DESC` have high number of rows.

- PERSON -     4638768
- PERSON_DESC  - 2040027
- #compareList - 26
- I have tried to apply clustered and non-clustered index on the tables `PERSON` and `PERSON_DESC`.
- On table `PERSON` I applied index on `pid, single_string_name, original_script_name, surname, first_name, middle_name`
- On table `PERSON_DESC` I applied index on `pid, desc1`.

Below is the statistics parameter

```
Table '#compareList________________________________________________________________________________________________________0000000001C5'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 1, logical reads 8055799, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 16, logical reads 43232, physical reads 5431, read-ahead reads 42753, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'PERSON'. Scan count 1, logical reads 42966, physical reads 1, read-ahead reads 10440, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'DESC'. Scan count 1, logical reads 7060, physical reads 1, read-ahead reads 7054, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'DESC1'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1, physical reads 1, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

What changes can I make to improve the execution time of this query?

Comment: We need to see the execution plan to advise.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Why is a cursor being used to perform a simple insert into a table? Is there something missing here that's in the original query?

Comment: Like @marc_s said, fix those old-style JOIN's. You're also performing a JOIN on those heavily modified columns which is going to kill any indexes you've got.

Comment: If there isn't something seriously wrong with the query...and this is taking 2 hours to run,  either your storage is seriously slow, or you're running this on a potato, because based on your statistics you're reading ~62GB and processing in 2 hours.

Comment: @ChadBaldwin what you mean I could have been running my database on a potato all these years? lol

Comment: what about potatoes in series?

Comment: @DaleK: well, you can slice a potato into what's known as "chips", and databases run very well on those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a massive issue of sargability i.e. due to all the function calls you make in your `where` clause. So very few, if any, indexes will be used. I have a few suggestions.

---

Firstly, if you have any way to restrict the records you need to test against before calling any functions, do that, put the results into a temp table and then run your function based `where` clauses against it. Something like:

```
select columns, compute columns that we can compute here (should be one side of the compare)
into #MyTempTable
from MyTable
where {my saragable conditions};

-- Potentially add some indexes to the temp table computed columns

select columns
from #MyTempTable
where {my unsaragable conditions};
```

---

Secondly, `OR`ing multiple conditions is a fairly well known performance issue. This can be solved with `UNION ALL` e.g.

```
SELECT {your query}
WHERE p.pid = pd.pid
AND pd.desc1 = d.d1id
AND replace(replace(replace(rtrim(ltrim(a.[Name])), ' ',''), ',',''), '.','') != ''
AND replace(replace(replace(a.[Name], ' ',''), ',',''), '.','') = replace(replace(replace(p.single_string_name, ' ',''), ',',''), '.','') COLLATE database_default

UNION ALL

SELECT {your query}
WHERE p.pid = pd.pid
AND pd.desc1 = d.d1id
AND replace(replace(replace(rtrim(ltrim(a.[Name])), ' ',''), ',',''), '.','') != ''
AND replace(replace(replace(a.[Name], ' ',''), ',',''), '.','') = replace(replace(replace(p.original_script_name, ' ',''), ',',''), '.','') COLLATE database_default

UNION ALL

SELECT {your query}
WHERE p.pid = pd.pid
AND pd.desc1 = d.d1id
AND replace(replace(replace(rtrim(ltrim(a.[Name])), ' ',''), ',',''), '.','') != ''
AND replace(replace(replace(a.[Name], ' ',''), ',',''), '.','') = replace(replace(replace(p.surname+p.first_name+p.middle_name, ' ',''), ',',''), '.','');
```

---

Thirdly the first two suggestions don't help you might need to consider materialising the data you are using in your `where` clause. By that I mean as an example taking:

```
replace(replace(replace(p.single_string_name, ' ',''), ',',''), '.','') COLLATE database_default
```

and storing that value in a new column in table `p` which you can then index. You may have to write triggers to keep it maintained.

In saying that, given part of your data is already in a temp table, `#compareList`, you should directly store the compare value in your temp table i.e. add another column which stores:

```
replace(replace(replace(rtrim(ltrim(a.[Name])), ' ',''), ',',''), '.','')
```

and then potentially index it.

Comment: Thanks Dale. yes it did help.